# sending sms from websites to phone without using GSM and GETWAY

Tags: javascript, php

which code can i write, that can help me to send messages from website to any type of phone with different networks.
i have tried to use GSM and GETWAY and now i want to look for the easy way of making it

Comment: you can use the email address of the phone, that's free. you need to know the formula to convert the number into an email address, which varies by provider, ex: 1234567890@vmobile.com, 1234567890@vtext.com, etc. there are some APIs to turn a phone number into a provider, then you can turn the number+provider into an email address. ex: https://www.google.com/search?q=verison+phone+email&oq=verison+phone+email

Answer (score 2):

You can't send SMS on a mobile number without any GSM modem or a gateway. So the only choices are:

1. A gateway - use it for professional support and reliability (costs money)
2. A GSM modem - needs advance technical skills and some good investment to get it working